# Selenium handle page refresh

Tags: java, selenium

Here is my code for executing java script on every page on web driver and get values from cookies based on my script. It works fine. but the problem is if the page is refreshed it is not working because I check previous URL with current URL. how to handle that refreshing of page.help me

```
         String s="Some javascript";
         String prev = driver.getTitle();

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(s);
        iflag = 0;
        Boolean record = Boolean.valueOf(true);

        while (record.booleanValue()) {
            try {

                curr = driver.getTitle();
      //Check if page changed or not
               ///help needed here
                if (!(prev.equals(curr))) {
                    System.out.println("changes");
                    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(s);
                    prev = curr;
                }
                Set<String> wnd_hndls = driver.getWindowHandles();
                Iterator wnd_itr = wnd_hndls.iterator();

                if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("about:blank")) {
                    int win_ind = 0;
                    while (wnd_itr.hasNext()) {
                        String wnd_hndlr = (String) wnd_itr.next();
                        win_ind++;
                        Cookie ck_pg = driver.manage().getCookieNamed(wnd_hndlr);
                        if ((ck_pg != null) && (ck_pg.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))) 
                        {
                            iflag = 1;
                        }
                        if (ck_pg == null) 
                        {
                            iflag = 1;
                        }
                        if (iflag == 1) {

                           //My operation based on executed javascript

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (WebDriverException localWebDriverException) {
                driver.quit();
                record = Boolean.valueOf(false);

          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing of page may take time depending on various factors. You should either wait for an element on new page of sleep till it changes. Try following:

```
//To check if page changed or not use this instead of simple driver.getTitle()
int i = 0;
do{
    Thread.sleep(500);// Or wait for element on new page.
    curr = driver.getTitle();
    i++;
}while(prev.equals(curr)&&i<10);
if (!(prev.equals(curr))) {
    System.out.println("changes");
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(s);
    prev = curr;
}
```

To refresh page use following:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Comment: I don't use driver.navigate.refresh for refreshing instead I use refresh button or f5 button..the pages are dynamic pages so wait for element on page wont work in my case..for example first i go to google (script injects) then i enter some value and navigate to other page (script injects again) as it is new page but if i hit refresh script wont inject.I want a way to solve that

Comment: You don't need to use it, I just mentioned it as refreshing page was part of your question. Do accept the answer if the other part was helpful to you.